# PHP Laravel SQLServer could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm trying to get my first Laravel project running with a freshly installed SQL Server instance, and my normal connections work. However, in Laravel, I get the error message "could not find driver" when I run the environment server with `php:artisan serve`.

> ```
> Illuminate
>  \ 
> Database
>  \ 
> QueryException
> PHP 8.2.15
> 11.0.8
> could not find driver
> SELECT
>   top 1 *
> FROM
>   [ sessions ]
> WHERE
>   [ id ] = FnziuCl4Bh7mfDbUW4F3E0OQKfryNLEd21vPSyF3
> ```

php.ini shows me that SQL Server is enabled:

```
sqlsrv
sqlsrv support  enabled
ExtensionVer    5.11.1+17301
Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize    10240   10240
sqlsrv.LogSeverity  0   0
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems    0   0
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors   On  On`
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=192.168.xx.xx
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=webdev_laravel
DB_USERNAME=webdev_applikation
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I tried the following:

- server restart
- clear cache

I read a lot of other threads with the same error, but I don't want to use PDO, and I think it's optional, or isn't it?